# wait for databinding before changing imagebutton image

Tags: asp.net, repeater, wait, data-binding

i want to do the same think us mysql sorting on colone, i have the table colone title and an imagebutton next, when i click on the imagebutton i databind myrepeater and i want to change the imageurl of the imagebutton after that, i'm doing like that

```
protected void UserRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "country":
            break;
        default:
            string criteres = e.CommandName;
            ImageButton image = (ImageButton)UserRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(criteres);
            if (image.ImageUrl == "~\\Data\\logos\\s_desc.png")
            {
                LoadSortedData(criteres, "DESC", 1);
                image.ImageUrl = "~\\Data\\logos\\s_asc.png";
            }
            else
            {
                LoadSortedData(criteres, "ASC", 1);
                image.ImageUrl = "~\\Data\\logos\\s_desc.png";
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Unexpected, my repeater is being databinded but the image url is not being modified, if i left image.ImageUrl = "~\Data\logos\s_asc.png"; alone without LoadSortedData which databind the repeater the image url change on click, any idea about that ?

Comment: What ImageUrl you had before entering the _if, else_ ? Maybe ImageUrl path not matches with those relative path strings.

Comment: i had "~\\Data\\logos\\s_asc.png" and the problem don't came from that , i sayed in the question " if i left image.ImageUrl = "~\Data\logos\s_asc.png"; alone without LoadSortedData which databind the repeater the image url change on click"

Comment: Is code inside `LoadSortedData()` wrapped in try/catch block ? Your code is re-binding repeater control, try writing `ImageButton image = (ImageButton)UserRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(criteres);` after `LoadSortedData()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void UserRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int bookid;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "country":
                break;
            default:
                string criteres = e.CommandName;
                ImageButton image = (ImageButton)UserRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(criteres);
                if (image.ImageUrl == "~\\Data\\logos\\s_desc.png")
                {
                    LoadSortedData(criteres, "DESC", 1);
                    image = (ImageButton)UserRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(criteres);
                    image.ImageUrl = "~\\Data\\logos\\s_asc.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadSortedData(criteres, "ASC", 1);
                    image = (ImageButton)UserRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(criteres);
                    image.ImageUrl = "~\\Data\\logos\\s_desc.png";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

thx Coder this code work for me.